# How to use Pandas interpolate function for long time series without getting a memory error?

Tags: pandas, out-of-memory, interpolation

I am using the built in Pandas Series' interpolate function to linearly interpolate missing values (nans) in a time series. However, for long time series (N=10^9) the code never stops running and eventually crashes..

A very simple example is:

```
N = 10**6
s = pd.Series(np.arange(N))
s[::10] = np.nan # Set every 10th value to nan
s = s.interpolate() # Linearly interpolate nans
```

For N=10^6 the interpolation step takes 0.06 seconds, for N=10^7 it takes 0.6 seconds, for N=10^8 it takes 6 seconds.

The issue starts when N is increased to 10^9 (which is roughly the length of the time series I'm working with). Now my computer just crashes... I'm assuming it's some kind of memory error, without knowing much about the internal workings of computers.

Is there a method to avoid this, without creating a slow for loop and splitting the time series up?

Comment: I've executed your snippet with `N=10**9` on my workstation with 96GiB of RAM and was watching RAM usage during the interpolation. Before starting interpolation iPython occupied approx. 8 GiB of RAM, during interpolation it went up to 52GiB and then went back down to approx. 15 GiB.

Comment: It's likely a memory limitation issue. You can cut your series in chunks and interpolate each of them.

Comment: @MaxU - OK that's a lot of memory! I'm surprised Pandas can't manage to split it up internally, but maybe that's just my lack of understanding.